# Bootstrap Thumbnails Grid Won't Fill Extra Space

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a list of thumbnails in bootstrap that needs to be lined up in a grid that fills the space above it. This jsfiddle shows the problem right now: the spacing between the li items are very weird.

Here's the basic framework. A ul with class thumbnails and then lis with class thumbnail and paddedspan3 to add a fixed width.

http://jsfiddle.net/PZmp9/

```
<ul class="thumbnails">
<li class="paddedspan3">
    <div class="thumbnail"><img alt="" src="http://www.cedarville.edu/~/media/Images/PhotoGallery/Alumni-BasketBall2012/abw-12_101.jpg?w=268" id="one"/>
<h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
<p><i class="icon icon-map-marker"></i>Place, Country</p>
<p>Thumbnail caption...</p>
<p><a href="http://bootsnipp.com/" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Open</a></p>
</div>
</li>
<li class="paddedspan3">
<div class="thumbnail"><img alt="" src="http://www.cedarville.edu/~/media/Images/PhotoGallery/Alumni-BasketBall2012/abw-12_103.jpg?w=268" id="two"/>
<h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
<p><i class="icon icon-map-marker"></i>Place, Country</p>
<p>Thumbnail caption...</p>
<p><a href="http://bootsnipp.com/" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Open</a></p>
</div>
</li>
```

Any idea on how to get the thumbnails to fill in the space in the top? It seems like the one on the very right is doing it correctly but then the rest just go all the way below it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try making your window bigger and you will see that more go to the top.  Are you wanting like three or four thumbnails per row?

Comment: I want 4 per row but they need to fill the space above them because some images are shorter. So they don't need to strictly be in rows just the same width and varying spacing depending on how tall the image above them is

Comment: Well sorry I don't know how to make the images stack like that using bootstrap thumbnails.  One option is to force a new row after 4 and then if you add the smaller images at the bottom it looks a little better.  Like in this example  http://jsfiddle.net/ApeW4/1/  hopefully someone else will know how to make the thumbnails fill up the space.